# IBM Cloud crashes nodejs server even if errors are caught

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-storage

I'm using IBM cloud bucket storage for my app. When I'm trying to retrieve a file that doesn't exist the app still crashes even though I handle the error. This is my code.

Exported function:

```
export const getFileStream = (itemName) => {
    return cos.getObject({
        Bucket: bucketName,
        Key: itemName
    }).on('error',(err)=>{
        console.log("we've got an error");
        throw err;
    }).createReadStream();
};
```

Where it's used

```
export const getCV = async (req, res) => {
  if (!req.params.id) return res.status(404).json({ message: "Invalid profile id!" });
  await UserModel.findById(req.params.id, '-password').then(async (details) => {
    if (!details) return res.status(404).json({ message: 'User not found!' });
    if (!details.CV) return res.status(404).json({ message: 'No CV found!' });
    res.attachment('CV.pdf');
    res.set("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
    getFileStream(details.CV)
      .on('error', (err) => {
        throw err;
        // return res.status(404).json({ message: err.message });
      })
      .pipe(res);
  }).catch(err => { return res.status(404).json({ message: err.message }); });
};
```

When `details.CV` is a bogus item id, then I get the error below.

My logs and the error are displayed in the console, but the server still crashes and requires a restart.
This is the error :

```
Server running on port : 9000
Connected to DB successfully
we've got an error
we've got another error
/home/paul/Documents/ProiectIBM/proiect-ibm/Server/node_modules/ibm-cos-sdk/lib/request.js:31
            throw err;
            ^

NoSuchKey: The specified key does not exist.
    at Request.extractError (/home/paul/Documents/ProiectIBM/proiect-ibm/Server/node_modules/ibm-cos-sdk/lib/services/s3.js:585:35)
    at Request.callListeners (/home/paul/Documents/ProiectIBM/proiect-ibm/Server/node_modules/ibm-cos-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
    at Request.emit (/home/paul/Documents/ProiectIBM/proiect-ibm/Server/node_modules/ibm-cos-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
    at Request.emit (/home/paul/Documents/ProiectIBM/proiect-ibm/Server/node_modules/ibm-cos-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14)
    at Request.transition (/home/paul/Documents/ProiectIBM/proiect-ibm/Server/node_modules/ibm-cos-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/home/paul/Documents/ProiectIBM/proiect-ibm/Server/node_modules/ibm-cos-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
    at /home/paul/Documents/ProiectIBM/proiect-ibm/Server/node_modules/ibm-cos-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (/home/paul/Documents/ProiectIBM/proiect-ibm/Server/node_modules/ibm-cos-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/home/paul/Documents/ProiectIBM/proiect-ibm/Server/node_modules/ibm-cos-sdk/lib/request.js:685:12)
    at Request.callListeners (/home/paul/Documents/ProiectIBM/proiect-ibm/Server/node_modules/ibm-cos-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18)
    at Request.emit (/home/paul/Documents/ProiectIBM/proiect-ibm/Server/node_modules/ibm-cos-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
    at Request.emit (/home/paul/Documents/ProiectIBM/proiect-ibm/Server/node_modules/ibm-cos-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14)
    at Request.transition (/home/paul/Documents/ProiectIBM/proiect-ibm/Server/node_modules/ibm-cos-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/home/paul/Documents/ProiectIBM/proiect-ibm/Server/node_modules/ibm-cos-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
    at /home/paul/Documents/ProiectIBM/proiect-ibm/Server/node_modules/ibm-cos-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (/home/paul/Documents/ProiectIBM/proiect-ibm/Server/node_modules/ibm-cos-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9) {
  code: 'NoSuchKey',
  region: null,
  time: 2021-05-10T12:37:47.764Z,
  requestId: '1b2c2405-ea63-4a8f-b81c-1746a0214cde',
  extendedRequestId: undefined,
  cfId: undefined,
  statusCode: 404,
  retryable: false,
  retryDelay: 96.14914686040396
}
```

Comment: Show the error and the logs. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @data_henrik I've added the error I'm referring to, but the exact same thing happens for all errors of that request.

Comment: You are not showing all the code. How do you call the function? How do you handle the returned exception?

Comment: @data_henrik I've added the whole fragment where the function is called. I have a "get" route to retrieve the CV of an user, which uses the "getCV" function. I've handled the error by returning a 404 status with the error message